# How does the connection between mySQL and a Php website work?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have successfully setup a localhost (Individual Installs) with Apache 2.2, MySQL and PHP, as well as setup a couple virtual-hosts. Currently, I am trying to teach myself command line in MySQL. The part I am lost on is setting up the connection between the database that I create and the virtual-host website I am working on. In my mind I would want to save the database for a specific website in the same folder that I am creating the website. However, I could be way off base. Could some body explain how this piece of the puzzle and how it works. I tried to Google it and all I get is information regarding Work Bench and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The PHP manual is your friend: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL server runs as a service (or daemon) on your server - so the folder (or directory) you put it in is set by the system configuration and has nothing to do with your document root for your web site.

In PHP, you will "connect" to the MySQL service using PDO or something similar and then send requests to the MySQL server using PHP commands.

When you are running the MySQL command line interpreter, you can also test those same commands by typing them yourself. This is helpful when you're debugging your PHP program so you can see the data that your program will get yourself in the command line interface.

I hope this helps put you in the right picture.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Google it and all I get is information regarding Work Bench and myPhpAdmin

[this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is the first entry on the first page when I google `php mysql`, it covers everything from installation up to code example.

Answer (score 0):

Very generally:

You need to check with your hosting company if they offer you locally hosted MySQL server access.  Using cpanel/phpMyAdmin, or whatever tools they have available for you, you can then login and create multiple databases as you please - each database maybe corresponding to one of your site folders.  Once you have created your account and your databases, you can use php commands from your website code to connect to/manipulate whichever database you want.

EDIT: I missed where you said you already have a MySQL localhost setup.  Now you need to login to your SQL server and create one or more databases and one or more user accounts for those databases.  Create an admin account with all the privileges.  Then you can use php in your webpage to connect to a database, using something like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "your_MySQL_username", "your_MySQL_password") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL Server " . mysql_error()); 
if(is_resource($con))
    $db = mysql_select_db($MySQL_database, $con) or die( "Unable to select database " . mysql_error());
```

See the manual for more ways to query the database and handle the results: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php